# Rails 4: Change Locale Issue (PRD env. only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, rails-i18n

I have a problem when I try to change the locale on my webapp. In dev mode (webrick) all is ok, but when I deploy on my prd env (Unicorn + NGINX) a strange behaviour happens:

For each flag i set this link

```
   <%= link_to "<button class='btn flag flag-#{lang}'></button>".html_safe, {controller: 'amministratore/localecontroller', action: 'set', locale: lang} %>
```

where `lang` is the locale.

Inside the controller I have this simple logic:

```
def set
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    redirect_to amministratore_items_url
end
```

The problem is this: When I click on the flags (on dev all is ok), the page is not reloaded but the locale is changed (checked with `<%=debug(params)%>`. This mean that the other urls inside the page (with default_url_option that set the current locale to all urls) have not the correct locale.

Example

1. Current state : (url in page)
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?locale=it - I18n.locale =
   "it"
2. Click on flag EN
3. Updated state : (url in page)
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?locale=**it** - **I18n.local =
   "en"**

The same requests between prd and dev are equals (headers, etc, etc)

Honestly I do not know where to look the solution...

Thanks

Comment: You use Rails 4? Read about turbolinks.

Comment: Although out of topic, I strongly suggest you only use English in your code, especially when naming things (I refer to `amministratore_items_url`). You never know when a non-Italian speaker will need to contribute or maintain your code :)

Comment: @rkon Thanks for suggestion. Infact the pluralize of italian terms is not a really good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using Rails 4, so this is Turbolinks issue. I'm not gonna go into details (you can read about them [on the gem page](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)) but solution is adding `data-no-turbolink` attribute to your button.

Additionally I don't get why you put button inside a link instead of using `button_to` Rails helper?